# How to make chart with week data

Tags: amcharts

I'm using amCharts.
How to make data driven chart with week data?

My data looks like:

```
[
  {
    "count": 6,
    "date": "2011-W07"
  },
  {
    "count": 3,
    "date": "2011-W08"
  }
]
```

and amcharts opts:`categoryAxis.minPeriod = "7DD";` `dataDateFormat = "YYYY-WDD";`

Here is my result [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amCharts can't parse dates like that. I suggest you specify regular dates with month and days (for a first date in each week), then just modify [`dateFormats`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats) for category axis to format as year and week.

```
"categoryAxis": {
  "parseDates": true,
  "min"Period"": "7DD",
  "bold"Period"Beginning": false,
  "dateFormats": [{
    "period": "fff",
    "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
  }, {
    "period": "ss",
    "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
  }, {
    "period": "mm",
    "format": "JJ:NN"
  }, {
    "period": "hh",
    "format": "JJ:NN"
  }, {
    "period": "DD",
    "format": "YYYY W"
  }, {
    "period": "WW",
    "format": "YYYY W"
  }, {
    "period": "MM",
    "format": "YYYY W"
  }, {
    "period": "YYYY",
    "format": "YYYY W"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "count": 6,
    "date": "2011-03-01"
  }, {
    "count": 3,
    "date": "2011-03-07"
  }]
}
```